# Importing FacebookSDK into a Swift app

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-sdk-3.1

I'm using the FacebookSDK.framework, freshly downloaded an hour or two ago (version 3.17, I think), in a new iOS app written in Swift. I have Xcode 6.01. I can build and successfully run the HelloFacebookSample project from the SDK folder on a device. But that is in Objective-C. I don't see any Swift samples.

I am unable to import the SDK into a Swift source unit via import FacebookSDK, which gives the error: No such module.

If I add #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> to the project's bridging header, it cannot find the header file. The framework is visible among the other frameworks used by the project, and I can see the headers. The framework search path in the build settings looks reasonable. It includes ~/Documents/FacebookSDK.

I've seen this behavior before with another third-party SDK framework. I am successfully linking against a framework of my own, but that is built from source.

Are there any further preparatory steps required for using the FacebookSDK with a Swift app?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use cocoapods to add Facebook SDK to your project.

Comment: Use CocoaPods. They are incredibly simple to use and save you a ton of time.

Comment: Here you go: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056648/how-to-import-facebooksdk-in-header-file-of-swift-ios-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like some people mentioned in the comments to your question, I would suggest you use CocoaPods. I switched over and its been great! I apologize in advance that this will be a long answer, but I tried to be thorough.

1) Install CocoaPods. Should be no problem I don't think (instructions here under the 'install' tab http://cocoapods.org)

2) Use CocoaPods to handle the Facebook SDK dependency. This means you **do not** need to download the Facebook SDK Framework and drag it into your project (if you already downloaded it, you can delete it now). To use CocoaPods:

-using Mac Terminal, cd to your project directory

-use the 'pod init' command, which creates PodFile in your project directory and sets it up. If you ls in your project directory now, you should see a file named PodFile

-open PodFile and add the Facebook SDK dependency. Here is what my PodFile for my project using Facebook SDK looks like:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'RatingApp' do
    pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.22'
end
```

Note that for other dependencies you want to add, you can look them up on the CocoaPods website. The homepage should have a big SEARCH field where you can type in the name of the dependency. For example, type in 'Facebook' and the first result is 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', with '3.23.0' to the right of it (that is the most recent version as of this post). To the right of the version number is a clipboard icon. If you scroll over it, you see what you should input to your PodFile. Note that scrolling over it shows pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.22' This is exactly what I have in my PodFile.

-close your PodFile, and run 'pod install'

-open YourProject.xcworkspace, where YourProject is the name of your project. Now you can start working! **do not** use YourProject.xcodeproj anymore.

These instructions are also here: http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html

3) Lastly, you need the bridging header. The Facebook SDK is still in Objective-C (as of now), and the bridging header lets you use Objective-C frameworks in your Swift project.

-create a new file in your project. select 'Header File' for file type

-in that file, make your import. Here is what my file looks like, which I named 'Bridging-Header.h'

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h

#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

#endif
```

-tell your Swift project to use your bridging header file. Click on your project target file, which is the one with the blue paper and 'A' icon (hopefully you know what this is). You should see 6 tabs (as of XCode 6). These are 'General', 'Capabilities', 'Info', 'Build Settings', 'Build Phases', and 'Build Rules'. Go to Build Settings, and go all the way to near the bottom under 'Swift Compiler - Code Generation'. Set 'Install Objective-C Compatibility Header' to Yes. For 'Objective-C Bridging Header', type YourProject/BridgingHeaderFileName.h, where YourProject is the name of your project and BridgingHeaderFileName is the name of the bridging header file you created.

You should be all set now to use the Facebook SDK. The benefit is that now you don't need to make any Facebook import statements in any of your files (I actually don't make any import statements at all). If you need another SDK, you can add it like the Facebook one using CocoaPods (assuming it is available through CocoaPods). So to me, the nice thing is you never have to make import statements in files, and you don't need to download any SDKs yourself = )

Answer (score 0):

With cocoapods :

Use facebook sdk in iOS.

Follow [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift) to configure cocoapods with swift.

Then add the following in your podfile.

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'ProjectName' do
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'
end
```

Without cocoapods :

Drag drop FacebookSDK ShareKit, CoreKit, LoginKit and Bolts frameworks in your project's Framework folder and make sure you "Copy" (by clicking check box while copying) those frameworks in your project and add the frameworks in your bridging header file.