# How to import FacebookSDK in Header file of Swift iOS application

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, xcode6

I am converting my application from Objective- C to swift . In my swift application I have created a header file as explained in [following tutorial](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-facebook-login-in-swift/) , but i am getting error **'FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found** rather than I imported facebookSDK successfully in my application . Please guid me how to import facebookSDK in swift.

Comment: Yes i downloaded a fresh copy of facebook-ios-sdk-3.20

Comment: Yes I followed all the stuffs that we need , it is successfully working in my Objective-C app but not in swift

Comment: I did same and working well for me

Comment: Yes I did it & I completed the requirements of info.plist too like added the FacebookAppID & FacebookDisplayName as well as URL types

Comment: restarted my Xcode & cleaned my application too , but still getting same error

Answer (score 9):

Facebook supports swift natively as of SDK v4.1, so ***bridging headers are not required*** now. (by the way, they also deprecated `FacebookSDK` in favor of  `FBSDKCoreKit` since this version)

Just import the module you need directly:

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it right:

1. Create a Swift project
2. File > New > Cocoa Touch Class > Language Objective-C > Create
3. Xcode asks you to create a bridging header, let Xcode create that header
4. Do the steps in: http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-facebook-login-in-swift/
5. Add `#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>` to the Xcode generated bridging header.
6. Build

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to your target's build settings:

1.In Xcode, if you go into the build settings for your target, and scroll all the way down you'll find a "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" section.

2.Set "Objective-C Bridging Header" to <#PROJECT_NAME>Bridging-Header.h

3.Now create a Bridging-Header.h file.Import FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h to Bridging-Header.h.

This worked for me.Hope will work for u too :)

Comment: I have a bridging header— the question states that the OP has already created one too.